# Change Node JS version in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

My Azure Mobile Service is running on Node JS Version v0.0.28

```
{"nodeversion":"v0.8.28"}
```

I have altered the package.json to utilize Version 4.1.0 which is installed on the Azure Server, but even after changing this and rebooting the server I still see v0.8.28.

I even modified the enviroment variables on the server, but after a reboot they just revert back anyways.

How can I change the nodejs version on Azure Mobile Services?

Comment: Shaun Luttin’s right. You can't upgrade NodeJS version on Azure. However, you can create an Azure VM to install the other version NodeJS and do what you want to do in AMS.

Comment: Within a few weeks there will be no need to create a VM. Azure Mobile Apps for Node (Mobile Services v2) runs on the Web Apps platform, and supports Node 4.x.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of July 07, 2015, **you cannot upgrade NodeJS on Azure Mobile Services.** [See this thread on the Azure Mobile Service forums.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1615a6a5-4fa3-49d7-a1cb-dcb062b33ef4/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-node-version-on-azure-mobile-services?forum=azuremobile)

[image: MSDN Answer saying that we cannot upgrade NodeJS on Azure Mobile Services.]

What you can do is check your node version:

1. Go to https://MY_APP.scm.azure-mobile.net/DebugConsole
2. Run `node -v`.
3. You can see exactly what version you're running.

[image: My Azure Mobile Services are running node v0.8.28]

Comment: Thanks!  There are some Node Modules I am trying to install that require .10 or higher, oh well...

Answer (score 0):

The v2 of Azure Mobile Services for node.js (Azure Mobile Apps) is open source and supports any version of node.js. Built on Express and completely customizable. Beta release scheduled for November 2015, but it's available now for pre-release testing and development. Github project available [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node).